# trouble with UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, xcode4.2

I don't really know why this isn't working, could someone please explain what I did wrong and how to fix it?

```
-(IBAction)working {
    workLength.text = @"Area =" Length.text @"x" Width.text;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Objective C how to format the string you're trying to set in that UILabel.

Do something like this:

```
-(IBAction)working
{
    workLength.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Area = %@x%@", Length.text, Width.text];
}
```